# Equivalent definitions for continuous linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:X\to Y$ be linear maps between two normed spaces (not necessarily Banach).

I thought about the following equivalent defintions of continuity (boundedness: $\sup_{\Vert x\Vert_X\leqslant1}\Vert Ax\Vert_Y<\infty$).

1. sends every bounded set/sequence to a bounded set/sequence.
2. sends any sequence which converges to $0$ to a bounded sequence.

The first one seems true by drawing a big ball containing the set and study that ball.

But I could not deduce that the mapped sequence must have limit zero. It could be the mapped sequence is bounded but staying away from the origin. However, I do not have a counter-example.

Comment: Try showing that if $x_n \to 0$, then there is a sequence $(\alpha_n)$ of scalars with $\alpha_n \to +\infty$ and $\alpha_n x_n \to 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. So take $\alpha_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Vert x_n\Vert}}$. A bit tricky.

Comment: Mostly. You need to handle the case $x_n = 0$ (for some, maybe infinitely many, $n$) separately. Or you modify your definition to also work for those $n$, e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{-1} + \lVert x_n\rVert}}$.

Comment: Your question is worded confusingly. The two statements you have posted are the same but then you ask a question not related to either of them. If the sequence you are mapping converges to 0 then it is bounded and covered by the first statement. Can you clarify what you are asking please?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not continuous, then there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $\|x_n\| \le 1$ but $\|Ax_n\| \ge n^2$ for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Then
$\frac{x_n}n \to 0$
but $\left\|\frac{Ax_n}n\right\| \ge n$ so $A$ does not satisfy $2$.

Comment: What if the sequence $\Vert Ax_n\Vert$ does not increase quadratically with respect to $n$, like linear or even $\log$>

Comment: @CO2 You can construct such a sequence. Since $A$ is unbounded, for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ the statement $$(\forall x \in X)(\|x\| \le 1 \implies \|Ax\|< n^2)$$
is false so there exists $x_n \in X$ such that $\|x_n\| \le 1$ but $\|Ax_n\| \ge n^2$.

Comment: I see. I could take a subsequence when it is increasing slower than $n^2$.